# How to make files optional include in MainSection of NSIS installer

Tags: if-statement, windows-installer, nsis

MainSection of .nsi file contains the files name which are bundled along with the installer.

I need to make a file which should not get bundled when install type equals normal and that file should get bundled when type equals costume.

`Section "MainSection" SEC01 

    - SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"  

    - SetOverwrite ifnewer 

        * if (installtype==custom) 

        * File "IncludeThisFile" 

SectionEnd`

How to achieve above in nsis.help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You usually just put optional things in another section but you can also do what you want:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
var IsSpecialMode

Function .onInit
StrCpy $IsSpecialMode 0 
${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $0 "/includespecial" $1
${IfNotThen} ${Errors} ${|} StrCpy $IsSpecialMode 1 ${|}
FunctionEnd

Page InstFiles

Section
SetOutPath "$instdir"
${If} $IsSpecialMode <> 0
    File "${__FILE__}"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

..and then run `MySetup.exe /includespecial`

Comment: thanks again for the answer Anders.i have done the same thing already, my question was not about to get/set the commandline var, If i put If statement in Main Section irrespective of ${If} value true or false, the file is getting bundled(i.e build expects the optional file also be present at compile time). I would like to know how to make few lines optional (including file) in MainSection. As I have observed there is no effect of If condition in MainSection for includin or excluding file

Comment: You can use File /nonfatal to include files that might not exist or use !if for compile time logic...

Comment: i have used /nonfatal, prob is even in specialmode is true and file is not present its just giving an warning not an error, So just wanted to know if any1 knows any better solution to handle this situation